# Apply rounded corners to gif with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have a bunch of animated gifs that I would like to add rounded corners to.  I have looked at this page:

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#rounded

But unable to get the rounded corners to apply to an animated gif.  Is it possible to do this with ImageMagick?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Imagemagick, you need to use -layers composite with a null: separator as follows:

Unix Syntax:

Input:

[image]

```
convert animation.gif -coalesce \
null: \
\( animation.gif[0]  -alpha extract \
-draw 'fill black polygon 0,0 0,15 15,0 fill white circle 15,15 15,0' \
\( +clone -flip \) -compose Multiply -composite \
\( +clone -flop \) -compose Multiply -composite \
\) \
-alpha off -compose CopyOpacity \
-layers composite \
-layers optimize \
animation_rounded.gif
```

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_mods/#composite

Because your output is GIF, which only supports binary transparency (off or on full), the corners will not be smoothly rounded.